# Proving if a permutation cipher is perfectly secret?

Tags: permutations, cryptography, information-theory

From what I've read, perfect secrecy in its most basic form, that the encrypted text reveals no information about the plaintext, be it structure or content.

A permutation cipher is easy for me to construe on paper as a reordering of the letters of a message, however I don't really know how to represent this reordering in a mathematically sensible way. e.g. The word "apart" becomes encrypted as "trapa".

As such, is there a mathematical way I can prove that a transposition cipher is/is not perfectly secret?

Comment: Do you happen to know any group theory?

Comment: I don't have much of a grasp on anything beyond the basics, no. I'm a computer engineer.

Answer (score 1):

I do have information after a permutation: I know exactly what the distribution of characters (bytes / alphabet members..) of the plain text was. If I see "trapa" and "olleh", I can certainly tell which one came from "apart"....

So it's pretty trivial to win the distinguisher game here (so no perfect secrecy).

*Added:*

Another, more formal, way to see this: one modern way to define perfect secrecy, is given an encryption scheme $\mathcal{E}$, with message space $\mathcal{M}$, ciphertext space $\mathcal{C}$ and keyspace $\mathcal{K}$, we have for all pairs of messages $m_1, m_2 \in \mathcal{M}$ and all $c \in \mathcal{C}$ that

$$P(\mathcal{E}(m_1,K) = c) = P(\mathcal{E}(m_2,K) = c)$$

where the distribution is taken over the uniform distribution of $K \in \mathcal{K}$ (which is the set of all permutations over some fixed length $n$ here). The message and cipher text space is just the set of all length $n$ strings over some non-trivial alphabet $A$.

Now take a message $m_1$ with $n$ many $a$'s, $m_2$ with $n$ many $b$'s (where $a \neq b \in A$) and $c = m_1$. Then the left probability is $1$ (for any permutation we get the same cipher text) and the right one is $0$. So no perfect secrecy in this definition.

Comment: That's if you know a permutation cipher was applied... And furthermore that you know the plaintext. What if the ciphertext is presented without that context?

Comment: That's not how the definition of perfect security works. The crypto system is known, but the key is not. The definition assumes the attacker must be able to distinguish between two different inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Take two permutations with the first one containing ‘a to z’ and the second one the numbers 00 to 19. Randomize both strings and exchange with the receiver of your message. This is the part that has to stay secret. Create a modus operandi that will after the encryption of each character change both permutations into two new randomised permutations which sender and recipient can reproduce. Now initialise your encryption process by creating two new randomised strings deriving from the permutations you exchanged. (It means too that you can use the exchanged permutation more than once as long as your initialisation process is non repetitive. – The alphabet offers you P26! possible permutations, which should cover it for your lifetime and the lifetime of the receiver.)

Now start to encrypt your message. Take the first character of your message and find the character and its position in the first permutation string. Record the number value which situated in your second permutation at the same position as your first ciphertext. Now use your modus operandi to create two new randomised permutations (alphabet/numbers) and encrypt the second character the same way as the first one. Proceed with the process until all you plaintext (message) has been encrypted.

Plaintext letter length, key letter length and cipher letter length during each encryption step will always be ℓ = 1 and offer a 1/26 choice for an adversary. Since each single letter of your plaintext offers a 1/26 choice for an adversary, the sum (all ciphertext letters as one string) of all these steps will offer the same. Remember what Shannon wrote: P(C = c) = P(C = c | M = m) for any c and m.

What you do when using permutations this way is removing the need for an operator in a one-time pad who selects for each plaintext character a key character and using modular arithmetic to create the ciphertext character. Each ciphertext character in an OTP always offers the choice of 1/26 when using the English alphabet. A key character in an OTP is always selected from a full set of the alphabet and it doesn’t matter if your plaintext in total is five or twenty character long. In the example above the selection and modular arithmetic is replaced by mapping a key character in the permutations and offering for the ciphertext the same choices as a ciphertext character in an OTP does.

[flowchart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BaYec.png)

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  Your answer will be better received if you use MathJax